# Setting webhook results in 'Unauthorized WebHook callback channel' . Everything should be fine

Tags: push-notification, google-api, google-drive-api

Time to go to SE, since this has cost me more then 4 hours now.

I'm trying to setup a webhook (`https://app.example.com/notications`) for Push Notifications coming from Google Drive API.

After having set-up everything I'm getting error:

```
    ...
    errors": [
        {
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "push.webhookUrlUnauthorized",
            "message": "Unauthorized WebHook callback channel: https://app.example.com"
        }
    ],
    ...
```

There are a couple of results on google (most of which are here on SE) that talk about this issue. None of the solutions presented seem to work for me. Needless to say, I would be pretty much tearing my hair out if I had some.

This I what I've tried:

As explained [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/push) there are some requirements:

1. Step 1: Verify that you own the domain. (Complete the site verification process using Webmaster Tools)

   Registered `app.example.com`, through Webmaster Tools. Separately also verified `example.com` although this should not matter. **Check!**
2. Step 2: Register your domain:

   - Go to the Google Developers Console.
   - Choose or create a project.
   - In the sidebar on the left, click APIs & auth, then click Push.
   - Click Add domains.
   - Fill in the form, then again click Add domains.

   Done for `app.example.com`. **Check!**
3. Note that the Drive API will be able to send notifications to this HTTPS address only if there is a valid SSL certificate installed on your web server. Invalid certificates include:

   - Self-signed certificates.
   - Certificates signed by an untrusted source.
   - Certificates that have been revoked.
   - Certificates that have a subject that doesn't match the target hostname.

   What I've done:

   - I've setup `app.example.com` with an SSL certificate.
   - Moreover the endpoint is reachable and everything checks out.
   - [SSL checker](http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html) has verified that everything is okay (5 ticks). Even the SSL-chain is setup correctly.  **Check!**
4. constructing a POST query

   - to the simple `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/changes/watch` endpoint
   - containing a `Authorization: Bearer x` header
   - containing a `Content-Type:application/json` header

Post contains a body as follows

```
    {
      "id": "someIdThatDoesntMatter",
      "type":"web_hook",
      "address": "https://app.example.com/notifications"
    }
```

**Check!**

I'm running all this through Postman (a Chrome extensions to test http requests) so there's no app at my side that can be interfering.

What on earth could be the problem?

Comment: DO you get any correct answer for this.

Comment: I had this same issue and finally fixed it in the developer console. In the domain verification tab, I had listed my site as _example.com_. It finally worked once I changed it to _"https:// example.com"_. Hope this helps someone!! ;)

Comment: @Richard: op here. Not currently working on this but for future ref did you mean to post `https:// example.com` including the space after the double forward slash?

Comment: Yes I did. I was trying to demonstrate the use of https. Without the space SO converted it to a link, hiding https.

Comment: I also have this issue and frustrated at it.  Did this get solved?  I tried using an icognito window to register the domain, I also tried executing this in my code rather than the playground, but nothing works.

Comment: @Geert-Jan did you get this working? I keep getting the same error.

Comment: @Geert-Jan: Many people are facing the same issue in 2019 also :)
Please answer to your own question or comment if you have solved this issue.

Comment: Op here. To be honest I don’t think I ever got this working.

Comment: To be honest from my side I have tried everything to make it work.. tried from different domains for ruling out SSL issues & domain verification. Create different google accounts tried almost everything from scratch 3 -4 times.. No luck. If anyone is able to crack this out. Please answer this question

Answer (score 1):

It was very weird but somehow it works.

1. When adding domain use complete URL with `https://app.example.com/notifications`

try the complete URL with a trailing slash when making calendar API call

```
{
  "id": "someIdThatDoesntMatter",
  "type":"web_hook",
  "address": "https://app.example.com/notifications/"
}
```

Comment: This solution works but be careful with expiration(i.e. when you expect the notifications to expire). It seems the notifications expire within minutes...still trying to figure out what might be wrong.

Answer (score -4):

Step 4's POST body address: "https://app.captured.io/notifications" should be "https://app.example.com/notications". Or the other way around. Either way, they should all match so we can understand whether that's merely a typo in your post or truly the answer to your question. :)

Oh; and in "https://app.example.com/notications", "notications" is misspelled. It should be: "https://app.example.com/notifications". ... Or the other way around if that's your thing :)

It's also worth noting, per their documentation:

> A watch request will not be successful unless the current user or service account owns or has permission to access this resource.